# find the min date (Closest to current date) if dates lies in future date and max date (closest to current date) if dates lies in past dates in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, hive, hiveql

The below scenario needs to be implemented in SQL:-

Apply group by "sl.No", compare "date" column to the current date (6/17/2022) and select a row to represent the group with below conditions

1. If all "Date" is in the future then pick a date that is nearer to the current date
2. If "Date" is in past then pick a date which is nearer to the current date

Here is the sample data -

| Sl.No | Date | status | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8/25/2022 | 1 | Y |
| 1 | 6/17/2022 | 0 | N |
| 1 | 8/24/2022 | 0 | Y |
| 1 | 6/20/2022 | 1 | N |
| 2 | 6/28/2019 | 1 | N |
| 2 | 6/11/2019 | 1 | N |
| 2 | 6/30/2019 | 1 | Y |
| 3 | 7/25/2023 | 1 | Y |
| 3 | 6/17/2023 | 0 | Y |
| 3 | 8/14/2022 | 0 | N |
| 3 | 8/5/2023 | 0 | N |

Expected output

| Sl.No | Date | status | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6/20/2022 | 1 | N |
| 2 | 6/30/2019 | 1 | Y |
| 3 | 8/14/2022 | 0 | Y |

Comment: why was 6/17/2022 picked for Sl.No=3 and not for Sl.No=1?

Comment: will SL.No ever have dates both in the past and future? (If so what should happen)

Comment: for Sl.No 1 there are 4 DATES      out of which a few are future dates so need to pick a future date that is nearer to the current date.So it picks  6/20/2022                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                         
 | dATES     |
|-----------|
| 8/25/2022 |
| 6/17/2022 |
| 8/24/2022 |
| 6/20/2022 |

Comment: @MattAndruff  yes it can have both past and future . If one future date is there then pick which nearer to current date

Comment: As per this "If all "Date" is in the future then pick a date that is nearer to the current date" - why in expected output Sl.No - 3 has 6/17/2023. It should be 8/14/2022 as its near to the current date?

Comment: Also for sl.no - 1 the nearest date to current date will be current date itself (if present in that group). In Sl.no -1 group date 6/17/2022 is present, so why 6/20/2022 is selected. Possibly there are few more conditions here that are not specified.

Comment: @pankaj yes it should be 8/14/2022 for SL.No 3. Sorry t is mistake

Comment: @Pankaj Current date  is not considered in this case 6/17/2022 is not considered

Comment: For a group of dates {6/20/2022, 6/23/2022, 6/14/2022, 6/11/2022}; what is the selected date? here we have two dates in future and two dates in the past,  6/20/2022 and 6/14/2022 have the same distance from the current date (6/17/2022)

Answer (score 2):

Please refer below query -

```
with cte as 
(
  select slno, dates, status, flag,abs(datediff(now(),dates)) ddiff from near_date
 ), cte_1 as
 (
select slno,min(ddiff) mdiff
from cte 
where ddiff > 0
group by slno
)
select cte.slno,cte.dates, cte.status, cte.flag
from cte join cte_1
on cte.slno = cte_1.slno
and cte.ddiff = cte_1.mdiff
```

DB fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jyyXPCQTMVgVnsUhMv5LuC/0).

Comment: Smooth answer.  Not sure if it will outperform the other solution  but I really like the approach of abs.

Answer (score 0):

IF you can fit the entire group into the memory of an executor then here's a solution for you.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions 

target = "6/17/2022"
df = spark.createDataFrame( data=[
 (1,"8/25/2022",1,"Y"),
 (1,"6/17/2022",0,"N"),
 (1,"8/24/2022",0,"Y"),
 (1,"6/20/2022",1,"N"),
 (2,"6/28/2019",1,"N"),
 (2,"6/11/2019",1,"N"),
 (2,"6/30/2019",1,"Y"),
 (3,"7/25/2023",1,"Y"),
 (3,"6/17/2023",0,"Y"),
 (3,"8/14/2022",0,"N"),
 (3,"8/5/2023",0,"N"),],
schema = ["Sl_No","Date","status","flag"]
).withColumn("date", f.to_date(f.col("Date"), "MM/dd/yyyy") #convert to date
 ).withColumn("target", f.to_date(f.lit(target), "MM/dd/yyyy")) #add target row
grpd = df.groupby("Sl_No"
 ).agg(
  f.reverse(f.sort_array( # sort descending into the correct order by field date.It is second column but all "Sl_No" are the same so this still works. Structs are sorted in order of their columns
   f.collect_list( # collect all rows for the group into an array MUST FIT IN MEMORY
    f.struct( # create a struct so we can keep all data from each row together.
     *[f.col(column) for column in df.columns] # shorthand to pass varArgs of all columns
    )
  ))).alias("grouped_rows")
 )
grpd.select( 
 f.when( 
   f.col("grouped_rows")[0].Date > f.col("grouped_rows")[0].target, # first condition of the problem 
   f.expr("sort_array(filter( grouped_rows, x -> x.Date > x.target ))")[0] # correct sort and remove items in the past  target] 
 ).otherwise( # second condition
  f.expr("filter( grouped_rows, x -> x.Date <= x.target )")[0] # already sorted descending so this works.
 ).alias("rep")
 ).select( 
  f.col("rep.*") # turn columns of struct into columns of table
 ).show()
+-----+----------+------+----+----------+
|Sl_No|      date|status|flag|    target|
+-----+----------+------+----+----------+
|    1|2022-06-20|     1|   N|2022-06-17|
|    3|2022-08-14|     0|   N|2022-06-17|
|    2|2019-06-30|     1|   Y|2022-06-17|
+-----+----------+------+----+----------+
```

Explain for this code has 1 shuffle:

```
== Physical Plan ==
Project [CASE WHEN (grouped_rows#886[0].Date > grouped_rows#886[0].target) THEN sort_array(filter(grouped_rows#886, lambdafunction((lambda x#993.Date > lambda x#993.target), lambda x#993, false)), true)[0] ELSE filter(grouped_rows#886, lambdafunction((lambda x#994.Date <= lambda x#994.target), lambda x#994, false))[0] END.Sl_No AS Sl_No#996L, CASE WHEN (grouped_rows#886[0].Date > grouped_rows#886[0].target) THEN sort_array(filter(grouped_rows#886, lambdafunction((lambda x#993.Date > lambda x#993.target), lambda x#993, false)), true)[0] ELSE filter(grouped_rows#886, lambdafunction((lambda x#994.Date <= lambda x#994.target), lambda x#994, false))[0] END.date AS date#997, CASE WHEN (grouped_rows#886[0].Date > grouped_rows#886[0].target) THEN sort_array(filter(grouped_rows#886, lambdafunction((lambda x#993.Date > lambda x#993.target), lambda x#993, false)), true)[0] ELSE filter(grouped_rows#886, lambdafunction((lambda x#994.Date <= lambda x#994.target), lambda x#994, false))[0] END.status AS status#998L, CASE WHEN (grouped_rows#886[0].Date > grouped_rows#886[0].target) THEN sort_array(filter(grouped_rows#886, lambdafunction((lambda x#993.Date > lambda x#993.target), lambda x#993, false)), true)[0] ELSE filter(grouped_rows#886, lambdafunction((lambda x#994.Date <= lambda x#994.target), lambda x#994, false))[0] END.flag AS flag#999, CASE WHEN (grouped_rows#886[0].Date > grouped_rows#886[0].target) THEN sort_array(filter(grouped_rows#886, lambdafunction((lambda x#993.Date > lambda x#993.target), lambda x#993, false)), true)[0] ELSE filter(grouped_rows#886, lambdafunction((lambda x#994.Date <= lambda x#994.target), lambda x#994, false))[0] END.target AS target#1000]
+- ObjectHashAggregate(keys=[Sl_No#708L], functions=[collect_list(named_struct(Sl_No, Sl_No#708L, date, date#716, status, status#710L, flag, flag#711, target, 19160), 0, 0)])
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(Sl_No#708L, 200)
      +- ObjectHashAggregate(keys=[Sl_No#708L], functions=[partial_collect_list(named_struct(Sl_No, Sl_No#708L, date, date#716, status, status#710L, flag, flag#711, target, 19160), 0, 0)])
         +- *(1) Project [Sl_No#708L, cast(cast(unix_timestamp(Date#709, MM/dd/yyyy, Some(America/Toronto)) as timestamp) as date) AS date#716, status#710L, flag#711]
            +- Scan ExistingRDD[Sl_No#708L,Date#709,status#710L,flag#711]
```

Explain for SQL provided for other answer: (has 6 shuffles)

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(6) Project [slno#980L, date#716, status#710L, flag#711]
+- *(6) SortMergeJoin [slno#980L, ddiff#981], [slno#984L, mdiff#982], Inner
   :- *(2) Sort [slno#980L ASC NULLS FIRST, ddiff#981 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(slno#980L, ddiff#981, 200)
   :     +- *(1) Project [Sl_No#708L AS slno#980L, cast(cast(unix_timestamp(Date#709, MM/dd/yyyy, Some(America/Toronto)) as timestamp) as date) AS date#716, status#710L, flag#711, abs(datediff(19160, cast(cast(unix_timestamp(Date#709, MM/dd/yyyy, Some(America/Toronto)) as timestamp) as date))) AS ddiff#981]
   :        +- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(Sl_No#708L) && isnotnull(abs(datediff(19160, cast(cast(unix_timestamp(Date#709, MM/dd/yyyy, Some(America/Toronto)) as timestamp) as date)))))
   :           +- Scan ExistingRDD[Sl_No#708L,Date#709,status#710L,flag#711]
   +- *(5) Sort [slno#984L ASC NULLS FIRST, mdiff#982 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(slno#984L, mdiff#982, 200)
         +- *(4) Filter isnotnull(mdiff#982)
            +- *(4) HashAggregate(keys=[slno#984L], functions=[min(ddiff#985)])
               +- Exchange hashpartitioning(slno#984L, 200)
                  +- *(3) HashAggregate(keys=[slno#984L], functions=[partial_min(ddiff#985)])
                     +- *(3) Project [Sl_No#708L AS slno#984L, abs(datediff(19160, cast(cast(unix_timestamp(Date#709, MM/dd/yyyy, Some(America/Toronto)) as timestamp) as date))) AS ddiff#985]
                        +- *(3) Filter ((abs(datediff(19160, cast(cast(unix_timestamp(Date#709, MM/dd/yyyy, Some(America/Toronto)) as timestamp) as date))) > 0) && isnotnull(Sl_No#708L))
                           +- Scan ExistingRDD[Sl_No#708L,Date#709,status#710L,flag#711]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if 06/17/2022 can be selected, if it can't then remove <= and change it to <.